# Two instance of FCMListenerService

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my app, I have an SDK which uses `FCMListenerService` to listen to SDK specific push notifications. Now, I also want to listen to my app specific Push notifications, so myself have a `FCMListenerService` subclass to do my stuff. 
But since, I added my listener service, SDK is not getting the Push notifications.

I want to just handle the push specific to my app (checking the notification payload), else leave the notification for SDk to handle.

Comment: Hi. Do post relevant code snippets. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your app's manifest you can have only one Listener Service with MESSAGING_EVENT intent filter(multiple won't give a compilation error). Whenever a notification is delivered to the app this ListernerService will be triggered. Inside the listener you can you can you check whether you need to pass the payload(message map)to the SDK or not. The SDK should be having a hook which accepts the payload and processes it in a similar way as if it was received from a ListenerService